# Downloading .net project from link

Tags: html

I found this site that has a link to a .Net project.

The link is to a folder structure.

How do I down load this project without SVN??

Is it specific SVN??

http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/nbdn_web_store/

[Source Code](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/nbdn_web_store/)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that either you [install svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100) (which is not a huge install), or you have a lot of clicking to do when you download each file separately using your web browser. Can't see any other alternatives, really.

Answer (score 0):

install subversion and check out the file with e.g. the command

```
svn co http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/nbdn_web_store/trunk/ ndbn_web_store
```

Comment: I ran the command so where do the files go when you do that??? All Iwant to do is look at the project not find out how SVN works.

Comment: it places it in the ndbn_web_store\ folder from wherever you ran the command from. Run it from a command window so you know where the working directory is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree that installing svn is a good option.

If you don't want to do that (and don't like clicking tons of links to download each file) you can use an offline browser such as [this one recommended by CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Offline-Explorer/3000-2377_4-10024310.html)